# How to get the value from an Orderable from a Wagtail Page, and then call a function that will return a value based on the input of the Orderable?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a Django/Wagtail project.

I have modified the HomePage in models.py and then in the Wagtail CMS, I populated the newly created fields of my homepage.

Here is how my models.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from django.shortcuts import render




class HomePage(Page):
    templates = "templates/home/home_page.html"

    background_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )
    hero_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    form_placeholder_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    form_cta_button_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hero_title_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hero_title_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hero_title_4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            ImageChooserPanel('background_image'),
            FieldPanel('hero_title'),
            FieldPanel('form_placeholder_text'),
            FieldPanel('form_cta_button_text'),
            InlinePanel('slider_items', label="Slider Items"),
        ], heading="Hero Section 1"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('hero_title_2'),
            InlinePanel('card_locations', label="Card Locations"),
        ], heading="Hero Section 2"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('hero_title_3'),
            FieldPanel('description'),
        ], heading="Hero Section 3"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('hero_title_4'),
            InlinePanel('column_one_items', label="Column One Items"),
            InlinePanel('column_two_items', label="Column Two Items"),
            InlinePanel('column_three_items', label="Column Three Items"),
        ], heading="Hero Section 4"),
    ]


class SliderItem(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='slider_items')
    slider_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    slider_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('slider_text'),
        FieldPanel('slider_link'),
    ]

class CardLocation(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='card_locations')
    card_location_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    card_location_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('card_location_text'),
        FieldPanel('card_location_link'),
    ]

class ColumnOneItem(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='column_one_items')
    column_one_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    column_one_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('column_one_title'),
        FieldPanel('column_one_link'),
    ]

class ColumnTwoItem(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='column_two_items')
    column_two_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    column_two_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('column_two_title'),
        FieldPanel('column_two_link'),
    ]

class ColumnThreeItem(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='column_three_items')
    column_three_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    column_three_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('column_three_title'),
        FieldPanel('column_three_link'),
    ]
```

Now, in views.py I have created a function that calls a weather API and returns back the temperature of the location (which I pass as a parameter). Here is the function:

```
def get_today_weather(location):
    """
    Fetch the weather data for the current day for a given location.
    """
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/{location}/today?unitGroup=metric&key={API_KEY}&contentType=json"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data["currentConditions"]["temp"]
    else:
        return None  # Return None if there's an error
```

Now, my goal is that when I visit my homepage [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) , I want to have the temperature displayed for all of the Locations that I have inserted through my Wagtail CMS (Orderable).

So if I would want to fetch the data for a new location, I would just go to the Wagtail CMS and add a new location in my Orderable.

[image]

---

I have tried many ways:

1. I tried to create a function in views.py that will get the value of the Orderable, then call the get_today_weather function, and then finally render the values in my home_page.html. The problem here is that when I visit my homepage [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it renders a completely new template and not my homepage (which I have populated with data from the fields of my Wagtail Admin CSM). Here, the data showed from the API, but unfortunately, the other fields that I have created vanished.
2. I tried in models.py to create a function for my model, which will call the get_today_weath function, and then pass the data into my Homepage, but that was without success.

---

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

First I have converted the get_today_weather function in views.py to my HomePage in models.py.

```
class HomePage(Page):
    templates = "templates/home/home_page.html"
    background_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )
    hero_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    form_placeholder_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    form_cta_button_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hero_title_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hero_title_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hero_title_4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            ImageChooserPanel('background_image'),
            FieldPanel('hero_title'),
            FieldPanel('form_placeholder_text'),
            FieldPanel('form_cta_button_text'),
            InlinePanel('slider_items', label="Slider Items"),
        ], heading="Hero Section 1"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('hero_title_2'),
            InlinePanel('card_locations', label="Card Locations"),
        ], heading="Hero Section 2"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('hero_title_3'),
            FieldPanel('description'),
        ], heading="Hero Section 3"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('hero_title_4'),
            InlinePanel('column_one_items', label="Column One Items"),
            InlinePanel('column_two_items', label="Column Two Items"),
            InlinePanel('column_three_items', label="Column Three Items"),
        ], heading="Hero Section 4"),
    ]
    def get_today_weather(self, location):
        """
        Fetch the weather data for the current day for a given location.
        """
        url = f"{BASE_URL}/{location}/today?unitGroup=metric&key={API_KEY}&contentType=json"
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            return data["currentConditions"]["temp"]
        else:
            return None  # Return None if there's an error
    def get_all_weather_data(self):
        weather_data = []
        for card_location in self.card_locations.all():
            location_weather = self.get_today_weather(card_location.card_location_text)
            if location_weather is not None:
                weather_data.append({
                    'location': card_location.card_location_text,
                    'temperature': location_weather
                })
        return weather_data
```

Then I was able to render the information in my HTML:

```
                {% for weather in page.get_all_weather_data %}
                <div class="single-weather">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="weather-box">
                            <div class="weather-img">
                                <div class="cloud cloud1">
                                    <img src="{% static 'img/Cloud1.png' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="sun cloud3">
                                    <img src="{% static 'img/sun.png' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="weather-containt">
                                <h3>{{ weather.location }}
                                    <span>
                                        <!-- Access the weather data for the current card location -->
                                        {{ weather.temperature }}°C
                                    </span>
                                </h3>
                                <h4>Oblacno</h4>
                                <p>Vjetar: 13km/h 236</p>
                                <p>Vlaznost: 65% </p>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define [a `get_context` method](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context) on your HomePage model. This can be used to add any additional variables you want to the template context, so you could create a `weather_reports` list based on the locations retrieved from the page's `card_locations` relation:

```py
class HomePage(Page):
    # ...

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["weather_reports"] = [
            {
                "location": card.card_location_text,
                "weather": get_today_weather(card.card_location_text)
            }
            for card in self.card_locations.all()
        ]
        return context
```

Then, in your template:

```
    <ul>
        {% for report in weather_report %}
            <li>{{ location }}: {{ weather }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```